# Python "0" to int

Tags: python, zero

I have a list with a string "0". When I execute my code I get an error because I want to convert this string to an int.

```
f = int(c[0])
```

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Has someone an explanation? I need this 0.

Comment: just ran `print(int("0"))` and it worked as expected, you sure this is your issue?

Comment: What's your list? If `c` is your list, you should pass the index of str character to it.For example if `c = [1, 3, '0', 2]` write `print(int(c[2]))`.

Comment: To clarify: I have a file which I open and I read the lines into the list. c[0] is the index! The first line in the file is 0. print(int("0")) works just fine.

Comment: If I use 1 instead of 0 it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
x =  "0"
print (int(x))
```

Result: 0

Answer (score 0):

I bet the value of x is not '0'  your result is with error since c[0]=''